Docker Compose for WordPress Containers Fails to Mount Local Volumes with ${PWD} Paths in Ubuntu/AWS
I'm encountering an issue with Docker Compose on an Ubuntu server (AWS) where it fails to mount local volumes despite using ${PWD} paths in the docker-compose.yml file. The setup involves a WordPress site with separate volumes for the database and WordPress content. Here's the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml:

volumes:
  data-db:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ${PWD}/storage/data-db
  data-wp:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ${PWD}/storage/data-wp

I've verified the directories /home/ubuntu/storage/data-db and /home/ubuntu/storage/data-wp exist and have appropriate permissions:
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu root 4096 Mar 31 23:08 storage/data-db
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu root 4096 Mar 31 23:08 storage/data-wp

When running the command sudo docker-compose -f ubuntu-container-bundle.yml up -d && docker-compose -f ubuntu-container-bundle.yml logs -f, I receive the following error:
Error response from daemon: failed to populate volume: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ubuntu_data-db/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /storage/data-db:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ubuntu_data-db/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

It's perplexing because the error message suggests Docker is trying to mount from /storage/data-db instead of the specified absolute path. I've tried the following to troubleshoot:

Checked that the specified directories exist and have correct permissions.
Used docker volume prune to clear unused volumes.
Restarted the Docker service with sudo systemctl restart docker.
Ensured there are no typos or errors in my docker-compose.yml.
Run with --force-recreate to force containers to recreate.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. Is there a caching issue with Docker Compose, or am I missing something in my volume configuration? How can I resolve this mounting issue?
Note: I'm doing this from /home/ubuntu/. When I build the wp container just using a simple reference like:
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/

It messed up my SSH server access. I did I little research and seems to be a conflict with root user - not sure yet. Anyway, that's why I'm trying to set the directories and even tried to put all the build files (yml and dockerfiles) in a separate directory (/home/ubuntu/build-files-wp) but it's also returning me the same error.
Config

AWS
Ubuntu 22.04
Docker version 26.0.0
Docker Compose version v2.26.1


Use . rather than ${PWD}.
version: '3.8'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - data-wp:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - data-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  data-db:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./storage/data-db
  data-wp:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./storage/data-wp


So it's not possible to use ${PWD} reference inside docker-compose yml files?

I don't believe so. Use ., which does precisely the same thing.

Would it be possible to reference one a directory one level up? Example (AWS Ubuntu): In my root directory, I have storage and build-files. Inside the build-files, I have my docker compose and dockerfile. I build the image from that directory, but mapping the volume one directory up. Something like: device: /../storage/data-wp. Would this work?

If you want to go up one level then use .. rather than ..
